# Octave + aquaterm: plotting not working

Tags: plot, gnuplot, octave

I am trying to set up Octave with aquaterm to plot my results. I've successfully installed everything with `brew`.

When I try to plot something using:

```
x = -10:0.1:10;
plot (x, sin (x));
```

Aquaterm opens but I can't see any result: there's simply no window, nothing is rendered on the screen.

However I can see `gnuplot` is working using:

```
set terminal png
set output 'testimage.png'
plot sin(x)
exit
```

Here I get the correct testimage.png file written and the sinus function is correctly plotted.

Is there a specific setup needed to get the result rendered on the screen with aquaterm?

Here is the content of my `.octaverc`:

```
set terminal png
set output 'testimage.png'
plot sin(x)
exit
```

I am working on Yosemite 10.10.2

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at (within octave) `setenv("GNUTERM", "aqua")`

or in your case `setenv ("GNUTERM", "png")`

Essentially the content of the GNUTERM environment variable is passed to gnuplot through a call similar to "set terminal "